# GET JSON with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a python script which generates a JSON and I can see it in http://192.168.1.171:17000/

In the Network tab I get

```
200 GET / 192.168.1.171:17000 json transfereed 40KB
```

When I'm trying to GET it from another webpage with javascript

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.171:17000";
var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

function Get(url){
    Httpreq.open("GET", url, false);
    //Httpreq.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json_obj = JSON.parse(Get(url));
console.log("data: "+json_obj);
```

in the network tab I get

```
200 GET / 192.168.1.171:17000 json transfereed 0KB
```

it's Response tab

```
SyntaxError: 
    JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

and in the console

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.171:17000/. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:
```

When I add

```
Httpreq.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

instead of fixing the problem I'm getting one more error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.171:17000/. (Reason: CORS request failed).
```

When I visit http://192.168.1.171:17000/ I'm getting my json, which is valid, and when I run my javascript code with another [json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jdorfman/awesome-json-datasets/master/package.json) it runs. But when I run my javascript code with my json it doesn't run. Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Remember Cross Origin error mean you are trying to execute a script on a server which is on the same origin (same IP Network). Both your browser and server are on the same IP network.Try to use google chrome with the extension Google Chrome web Server https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en . I willallow you to launch you www from a web server which will query you other server on your 192.*.*.*. network. That worked for me to solve the Cross Origin problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That header needs to be added to the server's response, not the client's request. In other words, you need to modify your Python app to return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. (How exactly you do that depends on what you're using on the Python side.)